# What law says women are not allowed to speak, Roman law, Jewish law, something else?

Tags: 1-corinthians, gender, law

Women should remain silent in the churches. They are not allowed to speak, but must be in submission, as the law says.

- 1 Corinthians 14:34

What law? Please provide a reference.